# Using a single large controller or multiple controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 3.2
Ruby 2.1.5
```

I am working on an application to create tickets (service orders). A ticket is going to have a number of sections. Rather than create a single large controller, would it be better if I had multiple controllers/models, one for each section of the ticket, and have a single view to display the sections in a single form?

I would also have a views/tickets/shared set of views (one for each section), and from the main view, I would render each as needed inside a div in the main view.

Comment: Without elaboration on the sections it is difficult to comment on your data model.  That said it is fine to have a single controller action to handle the form.  If you need to save data to several related models I would use a form backing object. https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/form-backing-objects-for-fun-and-profit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use multiple controller for an application like this until you know the controller object will start to violate the **Single Responsibility principle**, making future changes to the code base difficult and error-prone.